# Store has many Users through Permissions then Roles

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Entrust with Laravel 4.2 to manage user permissions and roles. However, there are many `User` per `Store`, but each store only has a `permission_id` not an associated `user_id` in its schema.

Here is the relational chain:

```
Store > Permission > Permission_Role > Role > User
```

Is there a standard way in Laravel to directly access the `users` for each `store` when the next closest relationship is `permissions`?

Comment: What do you want to do with those users and in what shape the result should be?

Comment: Just getting a list of all user data for each store would be useful. I could do this with a regular query, but I would rather use a conventional Laravel method of doing this if it is available.